# WSO2 EI converting Incoming Json request to XML and send it to WSDL Endpoint

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

When i am sending json to wso2 proxy service which converts incoming request to xml
using Payload Mediator. 
it gives me below error :

```
{
    "Envelope": {
        "Body": {
            "Fault": {
                "faultcode": "S:Client",
                "faultstring": "Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: unexpected XML tag. expected: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope but found: {http://fcubs.ofss.com/service/FCUBSCcyService}RATESMASTERQUERY_IOFS_REQ"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it is my sending Request :

```
{
    "Parameter": {
        "brncode": "CHO",
        "ccy1": "USD",
        "ccy2": "MNT"
    }
}
```

**It is my proxy service code :** 
Receiving Json and sending XML to endpoint

```
      <inSequence>
         <log category="DEBUG" level="full" separator="&#xA;">
            <property name="Request" value="=============Request============"/>
            <property expression="json-eval($)" name="Request"/>
         </log>
```

it is Payload Mediator that converting Json to XML that will be sent to endpoint

```
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                                 xmlns="http://fcubs.ofss.com/service/FCUBSCcyService">
                  <soapenv:Body>
                     <RATESMASTERQUERY_IOFS_REQ>
                        <FCUBS_HEADER>
                           <SOURCE>$1</SOURCE>
                           <UBSCOMP>$2</UBSCOMP>
                           <USERID>$3</USERID>
                           <BRANCH>$4</BRANCH>
                           <SERVICE>FCUBSCcyService</SERVICE>
                           <OPERATION>$5</OPERATION>
                        </FCUBS_HEADER>
                        <FCUBS_BODY>
                           <Rates-Master-IO>
                              <BRNCODE>$4</BRNCODE>
                              <CCY1>$6</CCY1>
                              <CCY2>$7</CCY2>
                           </Rates-Master-IO>
                        </FCUBS_BODY>
                     </RATESMASTERQUERY_IOFS_REQ>
                  </soapenv:Body>
               </soapenv:Envelope>
            </format>
enter code here
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$trp:Source"/>
               <arg value="FCUBS"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$trp:userid"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="ctx:brncode"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$trp:function"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="ctx:ccy1"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="ctx:ccy2"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <header name="Accept" scope="transport" value="text/xml"/>
         <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" value="text/xml"/>
      </inSequence>
```

**OutSequence :**

```
 <outSequence>
             <log category="DEBUG" separator="&#xA;">
                <property name="Response" value="=============Response============"/>
                <property expression="json-eval($)" name="Response"/>
             </log>
             <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" value="application/json"/>
             <send/>
          </outSequence>
```

How to work it properly ?
Thanks

Comment: Did you try by specifying xpath for parameters sent in request body. For example: <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//Parameter/ccy1"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than small mistake, your configurations looks fine

Mistake 01 : ctx should be changed as $ctx

Mistake 02 : If you exposing REST API you should create an REST API [1] not a proxy. Proxy services are to expose SOAP services in WSO2 EI.

Following is working sample for your requirement:

```xml
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="API_Name" context="/APIBasePath" version="1.0.0" version-type="context">
   <resource methods="POST" url-mapping="/samplePath">
      <inSequence>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://fcubs.ofss.com/service/FCUBSCcyService">
                  <soapenv:Body>
                     <RATESMASTERQUERY_IOFS_REQ>
                        <FCUBS_HEADER>
                           <SOURCE>$1</SOURCE>
                           <UBSCOMP>$2</UBSCOMP>
                           <USERID>$3</USERID>
                           <BRANCH>$4</BRANCH>
                           <SERVICE>FCUBSCcyService</SERVICE>
                           <OPERATION>$5</OPERATION>
                        </FCUBS_HEADER>
                        <FCUBS_BODY>
                           <Rates-Master-IO>
                              <BRNCODE>$4</BRNCODE>
                              <CCY1>$6</CCY1>
                              <CCY2>$7</CCY2>
                           </Rates-Master-IO>
                        </FCUBS_BODY>
                     </RATESMASTERQUERY_IOFS_REQ>
                  </soapenv:Body>
               </soapenv:Envelope>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" evaluator="xml" expression="$trp:Source"/>
               <arg value="FCUBS"/>
               <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" evaluator="xml" expression="$trp:userid"/>
               <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:brncode"/>
               <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" evaluator="xml" expression="$trp:function"/>
               <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:ccy1"/>
               <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:ccy2"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <property name="messageType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2"/>
         <log level="full"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://www.mocky.io/v2/5185415ba171ea3a00704eed" format="soap11"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <respond/>
      </outSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Working+with+APIs

Answer (score 0):

`payloadFactory` operates on the `soap:Body`, so you should not create a `soap:Envelope` and `soap:Body` inside the payloadFactory. Just set both `Content-Type` and `messageType` to 'text/xml', create the request using payloadFactory and send.